# Show a different message based on a column in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I've a model called Transaction, and it has the following validation:

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :paid_by, presence: true
end
```

By default, it shows the error message: `paid_by can't be blank` when I submit a form without populating this field, but I'd like to make it conditional: there is a field in `transactions` table called `transaction_type`, so based on `transaction_type`, I'd like to generate a different message.

```
if transaction_type is A, show the A message.
if transaction_type is B, show the B message.
```

Comment: you should write custom validation method for displaying different messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing would be to write a custom validation:

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :paid_by_presence_with_transaction_type

  def paid_by_presence_with_transaction_type
    if paid_by.blank?
      # whatever you have to distinguish this
      if transaction_type == TransactionType::A 
        errors.add(:paid_by,"A error message")
      else
        errors.add(:paid_by,"B error message")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't store error messages in your model like this. Use Rails' built in I18n.

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :validate_paid_by

private

  def validate_paid_by
    if paid_by.blank?
      errors.add(:paid_by, transaction_type)
    end
  end
end
```

Now you can do this:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        transaction:
          attributes:
            paid_by:
              a: "a message"
              b: "b message"
```

The YAML keys must correspond to your `transaction_type.to_s` values. So if you have `type_a` and `type_b`, the YAML keys must be called those as well.

Comment: You are saying right, but that's not what I asked. I wanted to have two different validation messages for a column.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily finish this by defining a customized validation:

```
validate :validate_paid_by

def validate_paid_by
  if paid_by.blank?
    message = case transaction_type
    when 'A'
      'A message'
    when 'B'
      'B message'
    else
      'Default message'
    end

    errors.add(:paid_by, message)
  end
end
```